# Global variable not changing value of time in 2 different functions

Tags: ruby

I'm running this code and it show the same time but i wanted different dates so i put the sleep so it would change the time in 10 seconds.

But is not changing @date_format

```
 r=Time.now  
 @date_format =  r

def self.asd 
puts  @date_format
 sleep 10
end

def self.asd1  
 puts @date_format
end
```

How can i do something like this?

Comment: Where does the code for setting `@date_format` live? Unless it's updated, it's not going to change--it won't be magically re-evaluated.

Comment: the code is just this. how can i re-evaluate @date_format?

Comment: By calling a method, or just calling `Time.now`. What's the point of storing a value if you want a different value next time?

Comment: because i want to format the date. if i have declared and put in the way i want i just call the variable

Comment: Then create a method that returns the current time, formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that may work for you:

```
>> @date_format = lambda { Time.now }
=> #<Proc:0x007fdaa4800b98@(irb):5 (lambda)>
>> @date_format.call
=> 2011-12-21 11:20:35 -0500
>> @date_format.call
=> 2011-12-21 11:20:39 -0500
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not convinced that's any better than just calling `Time.now`. Worse after the edit.

Comment: Probably not, but I can imagine there would be some good uses for this beyond this trivial example.  And the edit was just to match OP's variables.

Comment: This works but when i use strftime it doesnt work? r=Time.now    
 
r = r.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    @date_format = lambda{r}

Comment: `@date_format = lambda { Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }` then `@date_format.call`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time to change, you have to assign `Time.now` everytime. What you have inside @date_format is the returned value, not the method.

This should work:

```
def self.asd 
puts  Time.now
 sleep 10
end

def self.asd1  
 puts Time.now
end
```

**Edit**

Posible solution to your question on the comments:

```
class Test
   @date_format

   def self.date_format
     @date_format = Time.now
   end
   def self.date_format=value
     @date_format = value
   end
end
```

You can use it then, like this: `Test.date_format` and everytime you call that method, you'll get the new time and it'll update the variable.

Let me know if that helps.